# table header in email announcing twice(only first column announcing twice) in voice over(ADA) in iOS

Tags: html, email, accessibility, html-email

I'm designing email template with ADA(accessibility) compliance.

The issue here is, the first header in the table announcing twice when read through voice over.

For e.g. if Item is the first column, voice over is announcing like "Item, Item". This issue is happening only in iOS devices. For other devices it is working as expected.

```
<table class="setDisplayWidthInner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <caption style="text-align:left; padding-top: 20px;">
        <span style="height: 26px;  font-family: Arial;  font-size: 24px;  line-height: 1.08; text-align: left;  color: #000000;">
                        <h2 style="font-size:24px;margin: 0px;font-weight: normal;">
                                    Canceled service appointment
                        </h2>
                    </span>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr style="height: 22px;  font-family: Arial;  font-size: 20px;  line-height: 1.22;  text-align: left;  color: #000000;">
            <th scope="col" style="padding-top: 24px; width:30%; font-weight: normal" align="left">Auto service</th>
            <th scope="col" style="padding-top: 24px; width:40%; font-weight: normal" align="left">Service location</th>
            <th scope="col" style="padding-top: 24px; font-weight: normal" align="left">Customer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-hidden="true">
                <hr aria-hidden="true">
            </td>
            <td aria-hidden="true">
                <hr aria-hidden="true">
            </td>
            <td aria-hidden="true">
                <hr aria-hidden="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- body goes here -->
    </tbody>
```

Expected Result in iOS(iPhone devices) with voice over on:

Item should announce as "Item" only once.

Actual result in iOS(iPhone devices) with voice over on:

Item is announcing as "Item Item"(twice).

Answer (score 0):

Reading this - https://a11y-101.com/development/tables
...I see you're using table header tags (<‌th‌>) to achieve semantic table structure but I think you're actually misleading screen reader software.
My thinking is that you are supposed to use table headers to link content with the header but in your case you aren't actually providing any content in the table cells.
So VoiceOver is getting confused and simply repeating the table header because it can't find the linked content.

In this case you're fortunate that only VoiceOver is picking up on it, but I would suggest changing those <‌th‌> tags to <‌td‌>s and testing again...?

Comment: Actually I'm facing this issue only in iOS devices. For all other devices it is working fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: And we do have content in the table cell which will come as payload from json

Comment: Yes it is reading. Actually voiceOver is reading table header(only 1st column) twice before the caption. Once caption is read, the whole table is read correctly.